# How to filter tcpdump result by keeping socket recv() data only?

Tags: sockets, tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

As is known, the result of a tcp packet capture consists of packets that may be retransmission, out of order and so on, which will be filtered and rearranged by the network stack, and the application will call recv() to get the real data.

My problems is, is there any way to get the recv() data from a pcap file?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

If you want to reassemble the data, use a tool like Wireshark to reassemble the stream.  If you are really determined to access it using `recv()`, you will need to either extract the content and then transmit it in a new connection, alternatively, use a tool like Scapy to both read the packets, reassemble the data, and dynamically establish a new connection to send the data to your listener.